# MediaCodec encoder with raw camera stream requires surfaceview surface to work

Tags: java, android, android-camera2, android-mediacodec

I am trying to stream the raw camera feed using the camera2 API. The end goal is to stream the feed to a server where it will be converted and saved as an MP4 file when the stream is stopped. I would ideally like to run this as a foreground service.

I came across the MediaCodec class and looks like it would be helpful to encode the data before sending, but I've been having trouble setting it up using the camera.

I have the following code to set up the MediaCodec for encoding. The MediaFormat currently uses fixed values as I was testing it out, but the framerate, size etc are all supported by the camera

```
try {
    MediaFormat mediaFormat = new MediaFormatConfigurationBuilder("video/avc")
                    .setSize(width, height)
                    .setFrameRate(54)
                    .setBitrate(BIT_RATE)
                    .setIFrameInterval(2)
                    .build();

    videoCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
    videoCodec.setCallback(new CameraStream(this));
    videoCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);

    HandlerThread bThread = new HandlerThread("Camera-Stream");
    bThread.start();
    Handler handler = new Handler(bThread.getLooper());

    // The ImageReader was used to test if it's surface works or not
    ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 5);

    reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            System.out.println("Received image");
            reader.acquireLatestImage().close();
        }
    }, handler);


    Surface dummySurface = reader.getSurface();

    Surface encoderSurface = MediaCodec.createPersistentInputSurface();
    videoCodec.setInputSurface(encoderSurface);

    videoCodec.start();
    cameraManager.openCamera(
        cameraId,
        new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onOpened(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
                System.out.println("Opening camera");
                startStreamingCamera(camera, encoderSurface, UISurfaceView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnected(@NonNull CameraDevice camera) {
//              cameraInputSurface.release();
//              videoCodec.release();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull CameraDevice camera, int error) {
//              cameraInputSurface.release();
//              videoCodec.release();
            }
        },
        handler
      );
    } catch (CameraAccessException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

The startStreaming method is as follows

```
private void startStreamingCamera(CameraDevice camera, Surface encoderSurface, Surface UISurface) {
    System.out.println("Streaming camera...");

    try {

// Create a CameraCaptureSession
        CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback captureSessionStateCallback = new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                // The camera capture session is now configured and can be used to capture frames
                // Configure the MediaCodec's input surface as the target surface for the camera capture
                try {

                    CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder = camera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
                    captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(encoderSurface);
                    // Uncommenting the following line works for some reason
//                  captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(UISurface);

                    session.setRepeatingRequest(captureRequestBuilder.build(), new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session, @NonNull CaptureRequest request, @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                            super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                        }
                    }, null);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session) {
                // Handle configuration failure
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to configure capture session");
            }
        };
        camera.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(encoderSurface, UISurface), captureSessionStateCallback, null);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The videoCodec callback simply makes print statements now when the output buffer is available, however I would eventually like it to send the data off to a server.

I tried using a separate thread to call the `videoCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer()` but the output buffer was always empty with that too. For some reason the output buffer is empty if I set the target to just the input surface of the encoder, but it works fine if I also add a SurfaceView surface as a target.

I tried to replace the surface view surface with an ImageReader surface but that crashes and fails to open the camera with error code 3.

My problem is as follows:

- If I set the target of the camera session to **ONLY** the encoders input surface, nothing happens (the callback is not called and there is no data in the output buffer of the encoder)
- If I uncomment the `captureRequestBuilder.setTarget(UISurface)` and set the target of the camera session to **BOTH** the encoders input surface and a SurfaceView I have set up in the main activity to see what is being streamed, then data appears in the output buffer of the encoder however I don't know if the encoders output is correct.

But I would ideally like to run this as a foreground service so its not ideal having a SurfaceView, is there any way to make this work with just the media codecs input surface?

Thanks

Comment: Does logcat have any errors from the camera service when you just use the one output?

Comment: I've just noticed I do get an error "Receive capture error on unknown request ID -1". I believe I've found the issue. I am using an old pixel 3 to run the app which has 2 front cameras. I just realised the front main camera has a hardware fault and so the default camera app (and other apps) switch to the wide angle front camera. For some reason my app does not automatically switch to that unless I use a SurfaceView

Comment: I realised this after I switched to the rear camera and that worked fine